# Unable to upload image to azure blob storage android

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-blob-storage

I m trying to upload an image to azure blob storage. I am using java SDK for azure.I have referenced the libraries. Here is my code..

```
public void uploadImage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button click
    try
     {
     String storageConnectionString = 
                RoleEnvironment.getConfigurationSettings().get("StorageConnectionString");
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
                CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

            // Create the blob client
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();

            // Retrieve reference to a previously created container
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("classifieds");

            // Create or overwrite the "myimage.jpg" blob with contents from a local file
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("myimage.png");
             InputStream ims = getAssets().open("myimage.png");

            int len =ims.available();
            blob.upload(ims,(long)ims.available());
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         System.out.println(ex);
     }
}
```

Here is my error log

> 05-05 15:34:25.295: E/Trace(5195): error opening trace file: No such
>   file or directory (2) 05-05 15:34:26.105: I/dalvikvm(5195): Could not
>   find method
>   com.microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.RoleEnvironment.getConfigurationSettings,
>   referenced from method
>   com.example.azuresample.MainActivity.uploadImage 05-05 15:34:26.105:
>   W/dalvikvm(5195): VFY: unable to resolve static method 8441:
>   Lcom/microsoft/windowsazure/serviceruntime/RoleEnvironment;.getConfigurationSettings
>   ()Ljava/util/Map; 05-05 15:34:26.105: D/dalvikvm(5195): VFY: replacing
>   opcode 0x71 at 0x0000 05-05 15:34:26.550: D/gralloc_goldfish(5195):
>   Emulator without GPU emulation detected. 05-05 15:34:34.254:
>   D/AndroidRuntime(5195): Shutting down VM 05-05 15:34:34.254:
>   W/dalvikvm(5195): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x40a13300) 05-05 15:34:34.285: E/AndroidRuntime(5195): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `RoleEnvironment` class when your code is running as a `Cloud Service`. Since you're running the code in an Android application, this class is not available to you.

If the connection settings are in a configuration file, you may want to resort to another methods to read from that configuration file.